# Rails: How do I just show the current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Its a messaging app but it only shows all the users. How do I show the current user?

```
<%= form_for :conversation, url: :conversations, html: { class: "" } do |f| %>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>

    <div class="form-group">
        To:
```

This code works by showing the users name, but when its sent.... it doesn't get saved.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
```

The code bellow is the only one that works but it shows all the users..

```
        <%= f.select(:recipients, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>
    </div>
```

This is the rest of the code.

```
<div class="form-group">
  Subject:
    <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  Message:
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Type your message here", rows: 4  %>
</div>
```

Full code:

```
<%= form_for :conversation, url: :conversations, html: { class: "" } do |f| %>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>

    <div class="form-group">
        To: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
        <%= f.select(:recipients, User.name {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      Subject:
        <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      Message:
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Type your message here", rows: 4  %>
    </div>
```

Comment: where do you want to show current_user?

Comment: You're speaking about a "current_user", do you have an authentication system? If so, which one do you use? If you don't, how do you identify "current_user", do you use cookies or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know your current user's id, just change:

```
<%= f.select(:recipients, User.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>
```

To:

```
<%= f.select(:recipients, User.where(id: current_users_id ).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { multiple: true , class: "chosen-select form-control" })%>
```

Instead of returning an array of every user, and operating upon that, this will simply return an array of the one user you care about. That said, with a better understanding of your application as a whole, we could definitely find better display options.

Comment: `undefined local variable or method current_users_id' for #<#<Class:0x007f3a2c8b59a8>:0x007f3a40a0b2f8>
`

Comment: Yes, where I wrote current_user_id is where you need to put the actual current user's id. If you are working with user #1, put 1 there. Assuming you are able to identify the user with a variable, maybe you have this information in user.id or something like that. However you identify the current user, put their id there.

Comment: What can I do if I want rails to automatically choose the user. For example I got to a users page and when I press "message the user", it automatically adds the user instead of picking the user out of the rest

Comment: All you have to do is know who that user is. You need to have a variable with this information, and plug that information into the right place. If you need to save this from one action to another you

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?:

```
<%= f.collection_select :recipients, User.all.where('name is not ?', nil), :id, :name,
  { prompt: "Choose User..." }  %>
```

Comment: how do I make it automatically pull up the current_user profile page. Like I click on message and instead of pulling all the users on the site, it pulls up that user I am viewing?